# Equivalent of JPanel in JFace?

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, jface

In `Swing`, it was east to create a nice looking GUI display window thanks to the ability to add JPanels to JFrames and keep everything nice and organized.

I'm working in JFace now, and after looking around for almost an hour, I can't find anything in JFace that resembles JPanel. 
Does anyone know of anything that could help me accomplish what I need in JFace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SWT equivalent of a JPanel is org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite

Comment: Do you know why I'm having trouble putting a jface.TreeViewer in a Composite? It's just blank...

Comment: @Imray You are probably missing a layout. Read http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html